# Is it possible to write custom text on Google Maps API v3?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Is it possible to write a custom text on Google Maps API v3 next to the marker, or I can use only the info window to do that?

Comment: look's it is not possible... like the only way is to create transparent InfoBox window and write text on it... tell me if i'm wrong?

Comment: Can I add custom text(a word most probably) on marker in google map static map API..?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

To show custom text you need to create a custom overlay. Below is an example adapted from official Google documentation. You could also use [this library](http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/wiki/Libraries) for more "stylish" info windows

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
  </script>
  <script>
    //adapded from this example http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#CustomOverlays
     //text overlays
    function TxtOverlay(pos, txt, cls, map) {

      // Now initialize all properties.
      this.pos = pos;
      this.txt_ = txt;
      this.cls_ = cls;
      this.map_ = map;

      // We define a property to hold the image's
      // div. We'll actually create this div
      // upon receipt of the add() method so we'll
      // leave it null for now.
      this.div_ = null;

      // Explicitly call setMap() on this overlay
      this.setMap(map);
    }

    TxtOverlay.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();



    TxtOverlay.prototype.onAdd = function() {

      // Note: an overlay's receipt of onAdd() indicates that
      // the map's panes are now available for attaching
      // the overlay to the map via the DOM.

      // Create the DIV and set some basic attributes.
      var div = document.createElement('DIV');
      div.className = this.cls_;

      div.innerHTML = this.txt_;

      // Set the overlay's div_ property to this DIV
      this.div_ = div;
      var overlayProjection = this.getProjection();
      var position = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.pos);
      div.style.left = position.x + 'px';
      div.style.top = position.y + 'px';
      // We add an overlay to a map via one of the map's panes.

      var panes = this.getPanes();
      panes.floatPane.appendChild(div);
    }
    TxtOverlay.prototype.draw = function() {


        var overlayProjection = this.getProjection();

        // Retrieve the southwest and northeast coordinates of this overlay
        // in latlngs and convert them to pixels coordinates.
        // We'll use these coordinates to resize the DIV.
        var position = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.pos);


        var div = this.div_;
        div.style.left = position.x + 'px';
        div.style.top = position.y + 'px';



      }
      //Optional: helper methods for removing and toggling the text overlay.  
    TxtOverlay.prototype.onRemove = function() {
      this.div_.parentNode.removeChild(this.div_);
      this.div_ = null;
    }
    TxtOverlay.prototype.hide = function() {
      if (this.div_) {
        this.div_.style.visibility = "hidden";
      }
    }

    TxtOverlay.prototype.show = function() {
      if (this.div_) {
        this.div_.style.visibility = "visible";
      }
    }

    TxtOverlay.prototype.toggle = function() {
      if (this.div_) {
        if (this.div_.style.visibility == "hidden") {
          this.show();
        } else {
          this.hide();
        }
      }
    }

    TxtOverlay.prototype.toggleDOM = function() {
      if (this.getMap()) {
        this.setMap(null);
      } else {
        this.setMap(this.map_);
      }
    }




    var map;

    function init() {
      var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.9069, -122.0792);
      var myOptions = {
        zoom: 4,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map,
        title: "Hello World!"
      });

      customTxt = "<div>Blah blah sdfsddddddddddddddd ddddddddddddddddddddd<ul><li>Blah 1<li>blah 2 </ul></div>"
      txt = new TxtOverlay(latlng, customTxt, "customBox", map)

    }
  </script>
  <style>
    .customBox {
      background: yellow;
      border: 1px solid black;
      position: absolute;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body onload="init()">
  <div id="map" style="width: 600px; height: 600px;">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is awesome. I scratch my head, wondering why Google didn't include this by default.

Comment: Is there a way to change the label text size? Adding 'font-size: 30px' to the style block doesn't seem to work.

Comment: It worked great except I had to add `div.style.position = 'absolute';` in order to get the text to appear in the correct position.

Comment: Works great! But is there a simple way to position the box in bottom-center rather than top-left corner?

Answer (score 22):

By far the easiest way to add a Text Overlay is to use the `MapLabel` class from https://github.com/googlemaps/js-map-label

```
var mapLabel = new MapLabel({
  text: 'Test',
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(50,50),
  map: map,
  fontSize: 20,
  align: 'right'
});
```

Comment: I get an error "Uncaught ReferenceError: MapLabel is not defined ", how do you add utility library?

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/src/infobox.js"></script>`

Comment: But you need to use this one `http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/maplabel/src/maplabel.js`

Comment: @Legionar The above 2 links are not working. please check the link which you provided here

Comment: @codelearner Both links are working, also you can go one folder up, and you will see the content and also both files - http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/src/ and http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/maplabel/src/

Comment: @Legionar The links definitely do NOT work. Are you sure they don't require permissions or something?

Comment: A link that does work: https://github.com/googlemaps/js-map-label/blob/gh-pages/src/maplabel.js

Comment: @RobEvans It was still working last week, but Google moved sources to the https://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/source/browse/trunk/infobox/ simply use Google and you will find it. now the url to JS is https://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/source/browse/trunk/infobox/src/infobox.js

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/ says "We have moved to GitHub!"

Answer (score 15):

To add custom text to google maps, you can use a marker with an empty pixel for the icon:

```
new google.maps.Marker({
    position: { lat: 0, lng: 0 },
    map: map,
    icon: '../res/img/empty.png',
    label: {
        color: '#FF0000',
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        text: 'Hello World',
        fontSize: '20px',
    },
});
```

[Style options are listed here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/marker#MarkerLabel)

Comment: I was going to post this solution if nobody else did. I think this is the best one. It's silly that there is no ability to add a label without a marker now. They removed the label class at some point for some reason.

Comment: I set my icon to `data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAD/ACwAAAAAAQABAAACADs=` because then I don't need to save a blank image file. It's just a transparent pixel.

Comment: my icon disappeared when I set it to an empty string like so...
`icon: ' ',`

Answer (score 6):

It the text is static, you can use a marker and an image :

```
var label = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(50,50),
    map: map,
    icon: "/images/mytextasanimage.png"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The latest (v3) API recommends using `async defer` and a callback when the Maps API is loaded.

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"></script>
```

To make this work you need to define the overlay class from within (or after) the initialization when the `google` class has been defined. Otherwise you will get `google not defined` errors.

```
function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: { lat: 40, lng: -30 },
        zoom: 3
    });

    TxtOverlay.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();
    var overlay = new TxtOverlay(new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
        "<div>Have a wonderful overlay day</div>", 
        "customCSSClass", 
        map);
}

...

//adapded from answer above
function TxtOverlay(pos, txt, cls, map) {
    // Now initialize all properties.
    this.pos = pos;
    this.txt_ = txt;
    this.cls_ = cls;
    this.map_ = map;

    // We define a property to hold the image's
    // div. We'll actually create this div
    // upon receipt of the add() method so we'll
    // leave it null for now.
    this.div_ = null;

    this.onAdd = function() {
        // Note: an overlay's receipt of onAdd() indicates that
        // the map's panes are now available for attaching
        // the overlay to the map via the DOM.

        // Create the DIV and set some basic attributes.
        var div = document.createElement('DIV');
        div.className = this.cls_;

        div.innerHTML = this.txt_;

        // Set the overlay's div_ property to this DIV
        this.div_ = div;
        var overlayProjection = this.getProjection();
        var position = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.pos);
        div.style.left = position.x + 'px';
        div.style.top = position.y + 'px';
        // We add an overlay to a map via one of the map's panes.

        var panes = this.getPanes();
        panes.floatPane.appendChild(div);
    }

    this.draw = function() {
        var overlayProjection = this.getProjection();

        // Retrieve the southwest and northeast coordinates of this overlay
        // in latlngs and convert them to pixels coordinates.
        // We'll use these coordinates to resize the DIV.
        var position = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.pos);

        var div = this.div_;
        div.style.left = position.x + 'px';
        div.style.top = position.y + 'px';
    }

    this.onRemove = function() {
        this.div_.parentNode.removeChild(this.div_);
        this.div_ = null;
    }

    this.hide = function() {
            if (this.div_) {
                this.div_.style.visibility = "hidden";
            }
        }

    this.show = function() {
        if (this.div_) {
            this.div_.style.visibility = "visible";
        }
    }

    this.toggle = function() {
        if (this.div_) {
            if (this.div_.style.visibility == "hidden") {
                this.show();
            } else {
                this.hide();
            }
        }
    }

    this.toggleDOM = function() {
        if (this.getMap()) {
            this.setMap(null);
        } else {
            this.setMap(this.map_);
        }
    }

    // Explicitly call setMap() on this overlay
    this.setMap(map);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Here is working code:

```
#map {
  height: 500px;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

<div id="content">
  <div id="map"></div>
  <div class="centered">
    <h1>Text Over Maps</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```