# Text Overlay - Displayed in wrong Position

Tags: css, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have implemented the accepted answer to this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953922/is-it-possible-to-write-custom-text-on-google-maps-api-v3). When I run the html file, the text which I'm writing over the Google Map marker is displayed in wrong location (Refer the picture error.png). Can anyone help me to display the text exactly over the marker?.

[image]

[image]

Marker.html

```
    <html><head>
<title> Hi </title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

            function TxtOverlay(pos, txt, cls, map){

                this.pos = pos;
                this.txt_ = txt;
                this.cls_ = cls;
                this.map_ = map;
                this.div_ = null;
                this.setMap(map);
            }

            TxtOverlay.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();
            TxtOverlay.prototype.onAdd = function(){
                var div = document.createElement('DIV');
                div.className = this.cls_;
                div.innerHTML = this.txt_;                
                var overlayProjection = this.getProjection();
                var position = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.pos);
                div.style.left = ( position.x) + 'px';
                div.style.top = ( position.y)+ 'px';                
                var panes = this.getPanes();
                panes.floatPane.appendChild(div);
            }
            TxtOverlay.prototype.draw = function(){
                var overlayProjection = this.getProjection();
                var position = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.pos);
                var div = this.div_;
                div.style.left = ( position.x) + 'px';
                div.style.top = ( position.y)+ 'px';
            }

            TxtOverlay.prototype.onRemove = function(){
                this.div_.parentNode.removeChild(this.div_);
                this.div_ = null;
            }
            TxtOverlay.prototype.hide = function(){
                if (this.div_) {
                    this.div_.style.visibility = "hidden";
                }
            }
            TxtOverlay.prototype.show = function(){
                if (this.div_) {
                    this.div_.style.visibility = "visible";
                }
            }
            TxtOverlay.prototype.toggle = function(){
                if (this.div_) {
                    if (this.div_.style.visibility == "hidden") {
                        this.show();
                    }
                    else {
                        this.hide();
                    }
                }
            }

            TxtOverlay.prototype.toggleDOM = function(){
                if (this.getMap()) {
                    this.setMap(null);
                }
                else {
                    this.setMap(this.map_);
                }
            }

            var map;
            function init(){
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.90695894, -122.07920128);
                var myOptions = {
                    zoom: 4,
                    center: latlng,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: latlng,
                    map: map,
                    title: "Hello World!",
                    icon:"./bluepin.PNG"
                });
                customTxt = "<div>1</div>"
                txt = new TxtOverlay(latlng,customTxt,"customBox",map )
            }
        </script>
        <style>
            .customBox {                                
                background: AARRGGBB;
                border: 1px;
                color:#ffffff;
                position: relative;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body onload="init()">
        <div id="map" style="width: 600px; height: 600px;">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to offset the div so it appears over the marker.  An offset of (-5, -30) works for this marker and the number "1".

```
        function TxtOverlay(pos, txt, cls, map, offset){

            this.pos = pos;
            this.txt_ = txt;
            this.cls_ = cls;
            this.map_ = map;
            this.offset_ = offset;
            this.div_ = null;
            this.setMap(map);
        }

        TxtOverlay.prototype.onAdd = function(){
            var div = document.createElement('DIV');
            div.className = this.cls_;
            div.innerHTML = this.txt_;                
            this.div_ = div;
            var overlayProjection = this.getProjection();
            var position = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.pos);
            div.style.left = ( position.x + this.offset_.x) + 'px';
            div.style.top = ( position.y + this.offset_.y)+ 'px';                
            var panes = this.getPanes();
            panes.floatPane.appendChild(div);
        }
        TxtOverlay.prototype.draw = function(){
            var overlayProjection = this.getProjection();
            var position = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.pos);
            var div = this.div_;
            div.style.left = ( position.x + this.offset_.x) + 'px';
            div.style.top = ( position.y + this.offset_.y)+ 'px';                
        }

        txt = new TxtOverlay(latlng,customTxt,"customBox",map,new google.maps.Point(-5,-30) )
```

[Example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_simpleMap_SOlabelledMarker2a.html)

you might also look at[the MarkerWithLabel utility library](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerwithlabel/docs/reference.html)

[Example](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerwithlabel/examples/lettered.html)