# Google maps API v3, set always visible title

Tags: javascript, google-maps

If you go on google earth and add a placemark, the title is visible without a mouseover. Adding a marker and setting a title with the google maps api, like this

```
marker = new google.maps.Marker({position:latLng(35.734268, -78.873471), map: map, title:"Test title"});
```

Only show the title upon mouseover. Is there anyway to make it always display, or any way to achieve something similar with another type of overlay? latLng() is just a function I wrote, by the way. Thank you for your time.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953922/is-it-possible-to-write-custom-text-on-google-maps-api-v3