# Static Google Map: Is it possible to add Text to the Marker

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-static-api

In my Android  application , i have placed on ImageView. And I call the below mentioned url to get the static map image (bitmap image). And i placed that bitmap map image into the imageview.
I followed the developer site for displaying the static map.
**[Static Map URL](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Brooklyn%20Bridge,New%20York,NY&zoom=13&size=600x300&maptype=roadmap&markers=color%3ablue%7Clabel%3aXYZ%7C40.702147,-74.015794&markers=color%3agreen%7Clabel%3aG%7C40.711614,-74.012318&markers=color%3ared%7Ccolor%3ared%7Clabel%3aC%7C40.718217,-73.998284&sensor=false)**

*Edit* Added Android tag.

I just want to need my custom text to the markers like instead of G,C,S i want to display "`Start`","`Middle`","`End`".

Comment: have you got the solution? I need it. please share

Comment: (+1) This would also be useful for jasper report, so if anyone come's up with a solution it would be nice...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953922/is-it-possible-to-write-custom-text-on-google-maps-api-v3/3955258

Answer (score 0):

add only one char on lable in static google map,
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=300x300&zoom=getZoom%28%29&markers=color:blue|**label:R**|23.01181690,72.52326790&key="Your Google Browser Key"