# How to show label and custom icon on JasperReport map?

Tags: google-maps, jasper-reports

I have read [JasperReports - Map Component Sample](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/map/index.html) and tried below code:

```xml
....
<componentElement>
    <reportElement uuid="d16ce41f-66bd-4fdb-9d6c-31e661b0f16f" key="" positionType="Float" 
      stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="32" y="0" width="480" height="311"/>

    <mp:map xmlns:mp="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components
       http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">

        <mp:latitudeExpression><![CDATA[1.311378f]]></mp:latitudeExpression>
        <mp:longitudeExpression><![CDATA[103.826637f]]></mp:longitudeExpression>
        <mp:zoomExpression><![CDATA[12]]></mp:zoomExpression>
        <mp:markerData>
            <mp:item>
                <mp:itemProperty name="latitude">
                    <valueExpression><![CDATA[1.285979f]]></valueExpression>
                </mp:itemProperty>
                <mp:itemProperty name="longitude">
                    <valueExpression><![CDATA[103.838997f]]></valueExpression>
                </mp:itemProperty>
                <mp:itemProperty name="title">
                    <valueExpression><![CDATA["asdasd"]]></valueExpression>
                </mp:itemProperty>
                <mp:itemProperty name="icon.url">
                    <valueExpression><![CDATA["C:\\Users\\Desktop\\img.ico"]]></valueExpression>
                </mp:itemProperty>
                <mp:itemProperty name="icon.height">
                    <valueExpression><![CDATA[100]]></valueExpression>
                </mp:itemProperty>
                <mp:itemProperty name="icon.width">
                    <valueExpression><![CDATA[100]]></valueExpression>
                </mp:itemProperty>
            </mp:item>
        </mp:markerData>
    </mp:map>
</componentElement>
....
```

The map is appeared in preview but the label/title not appear and icon seems not changed from default.

How to show the label and custom icon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the map component in jasper report, you are using the

[Google static maps >> MarkerOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerOptions)

**icon.url**

For `<mp:itemProperty name="icon.url">` you need to provided an image url that is available on internet (the map is generated by google). Google can't access your local image `C:\\Users\\Desktop\\img.ico`, not even if you url encode it `file:/C:/User/Desktop/img.ico` it need to be something like `"http://www.jdd.it/favicon.ico"`. Try to remove your internet connection and you will see that the map is not generated anymore.

**title**

> Type:  string
>   **Rollover text**. Only applies to point geometries.

So `title` this is not a label but a **Rollover text**

I guess the question continues, *how to add a text above my marker in google static map?*

I would state you can't!, but this always dangerous..., If you find a way please let me know. There is one question on SO asking this but does not have a valid answer for us.

[Static Google Map: Is it possible to add Text to the Marker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20702299/static-google-map-is-it-possible-to-add-text-to-the-marker)

Same issue for wordpress users.

[show-title-on-static-maps](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/show-title-on-static-maps)

The only way that I know of adding some text (1 letter in uppercase), is by the `label` attribute (note: you need to remove all icon attributes)

```
<mp:itemProperty name="label">
  <valueExpression><![CDATA["P"]]></valueExpression>
</mp:itemProperty>
```

[image: P Marker]

> P = Petter

I guess since you are using jasper report, your solution becomes adding label decriptions below map, like I did in this post.

Or use customize images and put some label description of them below maps.

Or if the position of map is static (no dynamic datasource), drag some `<textField>` on top of it ;)

Comment: Im no longer working with this but yes you're right, the label descriptions is actually all I need last time!