# Google maps text next to marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm trying to make weather forecast using google map and wunderground api (since google weather layer is deprecated).

I managed to apply custom icon markers for weather but I'm not sure how would I add text next to them just like they did https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-weather

Here is my piece of code

```
     var markers = [
        ["London", 46.29999924, 16.37999916, 'http://api.wunderground.com/api/my_api_key/conditions/q/UK/London.json'],
        ["Manchester", 44.860735, 13.846721, 'http://api.wunderground.com/api/my_api_key/conditions/q/UK/Manchester.json'],
...
     ];

   // for each city grab its json file and generate new marker
 $.each(markers, function(i, value){
       $.ajax({
                url : markers[i][3],
                dataType : "jsonp",
                success : function(data) {

                    var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
                    bounds.extend(position);
                    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: position,
                        map: map,
                        title: markers[i][0],
                        icon: 'path_to_icon',
                    });
            map.fitBounds(bounds);

        }
    });
```

answer on this page works somewhat [Is it possible to write custom text on Google Maps API v3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953922/is-it-possible-to-write-custom-text-on-google-maps-api-v3) its just that i cant reposition text (it appears in corner and styling with css using "position: relative; top: -20px;" doesnt work).

It also has a lot of code and I was hoping there is a better soluton nowadays since that reply was made in 2010. Thats like "Once upon a time..." in terms of web technologies :)

Comment: Maybe [MarkerWithLabel](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerwithlabel/docs/examples.html)?

Comment: thank you, i managed to make it work. but is it possible to have two labels for one marker? one for city and one for temperature. or some way to split one label?

Comment: Quoting [Marcello](http://stackoverflow.com/users/408519/marcelo) "Motto2: Everything is possible, you just have to code it." That said, the "label" on the MarkerWithLabel is just a div, you can do with it as you want.