# How to calculate distance between two tracer javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have the following code that generates two TRACER and shows them in a map, and also, shows the union between two points.

```
<?php 
$latitudInicio = $_GET['latitudInicio'];
$longitudInicio = $_GET['longitudInicio'];
$latitudFin = $_GET['latitudFin'];
$longitudFin = $_GET['longitudFin'];
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <body>
  <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 700px;"></div>
   <script>
    function initMap() {
        var inicio = {lat: <?php echo $latitudInicio ?>, lng: <?php echo $longitudInicio ?>};
        var fin = {lat: <?php echo $latitudFin ?>, lng: <?php echo $longitudFin ?>};
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: inicio,
            zoom: 7
        });

        var inicioMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: inicio,
            map: map,
            title: '<?php echo $latitudInicio ?> <?php echo $longitudInicio ?>'
        });
        var finMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: fin,
            map: map,
            title: '<?php echo $latitudFin ?> <?php echo $longitudFin ?>'
        });

        var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
            map: map,
            suppressMarkers: true
        });

        var request = {
            destination: fin,
            origin: inicio,
            travelMode: 'DRIVING'
        };

        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
        directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
            if (status == 'OK') {
                // Display the route on the map.
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            }
        });
    }

   </script>
   <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
  </body>
 </html>
```

I need to calculate the distance and time between both TRACER and show them in an INPUT, LABEL, etc.

Seeing the documentation:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/start?hl=es

I made it to this code... this brings a JSON but I don't get how to implement it in HTML.

```
 {
   "destination_addresses" : [ "New York, NY, USA" ],
 "origin_addresses" : [ "Washington, DC, USA" ],
 "rows" : [
    {
       "elements" : [
         {
           "distance" : {
                "text" : "225 mi",
              "value" : 361715
           },
           "duration" : {
              "text" : "3 hours 49 mins",
              "value" : 13725
           },
           "status" : "OK"
           }
        ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

How do I implement this to display it in a label?

Answer (score 0):

If I got this right you are trying to display some data from JSON on web page? Or directly in maps (that probably has some API to do so).

If you only need to read the JSON and get the data out:

```
var dataObject = JSON.parse(yourJson)
```

and then work with it like with regular object in JS. Let's say you need distance in miles displayed you can do:

```
var distance = dataObject.rows.elements.distance.text
```

and then put this in some HTML element (this binding depends what libs and frameworks you use but vanilla would be)

1 -  add an id tag to an element of your choosing, let's say it's paragraph

```
 <p id="distanceMiles"></p>
```

2 -  set text to that element from JS once you parsed the info from JSON

```
document.getElementById("distanceMiles").innerHTML = distance;
```

If you need text directly on maps, I never worked GM API but this post explains it:

[how to make overlay GM API v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953922/is-it-possible-to-write-custom-text-on-google-maps-api-v3)

Comment: Hello, I'm very new to the programming world and I would not be understanding you. I have this URL to which I pass the start and end data per variable in this way: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=<?php echo $direccionInicio;?>&destinations=<?php echo $direccionFin;?>&key=api_key'         This URL is the one I have to put inside the JSON:
var dataObject = JSON.parse (URL) ?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/start is the API for CALCULATING the distance if you give origin and destination. That is where from you obtain distance not where you post it. I am now not sure what do you wanna do with that distance, I thought you wanted to simply use google API to calculate it, then parse JSON and display it in your site.

Comment: That's what I need, get the distance between two MARKER and display it on a label. I apologize for the time that I'm making you lose, what I do not understand of your code is the part of var dataObject = JSON.parse (yourJson) I do not know what to do there so that telling you here starts and here ends show me the distance that there are among those points.

Comment: I thought you obtained JSON through google API described here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/start they described how to do it with an example: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=Washington,DC&destinations=New+York+City,NY&key=YOUR_API_KEY Notice you need to have API key to make the request and you have to put it to the end of request URL.

Comment: Here is how you obtain API key: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/get-api-key

Comment: Yes, I took it into account and I did, I put the API and the URL returns me data, what I do not understand is how to pass those data to the var dataObject = JSON.parse (yourJson), if in the dataObjet I put the code that I shows the URL always the beginning and end are going to be that data, I need to start and end are dynamic to pass through a form a start and finish, and the page that receives them calculate the distance, always start and end van to vary

Answer (score 0):

[Look, with this code shows me distance and time but they are static data, I have two PHP variables of start and end I need to VAR ANSWER be equal to the address of start and end that I pass through PHP variables, since they are never going to be same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utCE8.png)